# mongodb: how does it behave when two clients manipulate the same collection?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have two clients (python) manipulate a same collection, the collection is used as a pool, and every single record int the collection can only be used in one of the client. I am using below code to ensure it(it's not critical system, so a little bit error can be tolerated).

```
for i in range(100):
    record = collection.find_one({"used1":{"$exists":False}})
    record["used1"] = True
    collection.save(record)
    ...do sth I want...
```

But I found that sometimes the two clients are not synced, the local client get the record and after 10 seconds the remote client will also the the same record.

Actually if the 2 clients get the records in less than 2 seconds, that is toleratable, but 10 seconds is just too long.

I think there are buffer/sync issue here, what I can do to reduce such problems?

Comment: What versions of MongoDB and Python client library are you using?

Comment: read about atomic updates and findAndModify in particular here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe - meaning it does not assure that two clients cannot both update the record["used"] field to "True" and both think that they were first/only to do so.

What you need to use is the [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) command which will atomically update the record with "True" if the field does not exist and then return that same record to the client that it just updated.

This guarantees that each document will only be worked on by one thread, however, you still have to deal with the same problem your code has now - if a client process dies after setting this "used1" field to true but before it does its work, you will have your data in an inconsistent state.